# How to Use an Outside Variable Inside a For Loop (Scope)

Tags: php, variables, scope

Simple question that I haven't seen answered anywhere:

How can I use an outside `$variable`, inside a `for` loop?

In my PHP code, I have a `SplDoubleyLinkedList` full of friends names, and I am looping through them one by one to use in an `if` statement that compares the current friend to the `$friend` name parameter. How can I change or orient the `$idx` variable so that it is seen within the loop and if statement?

This is not a question related to `SplDoubleyLinkedList`, rather it is just to `scoping`.

```js
<?php

  function removeFriend($friendsList, $friend)
  {
    $idx = null; //how can I set this index variable from the inside of the for loop?
    for ($friendsList->rewind(); $friendsList->valid(); $friendsList->next()) {
      if($friendsList->current() === $friend){
        $idx = $friendsList->key(); //"$idx is declared but not used."
      }
    }
  }

?>
```

This is a generalized example of my issue:

```js
<?php

function test()
  {
    $test = 0; //how can I set this index variable from the inside of the for loop?
    for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
      $test = 1; //"$idx is declared but not used."
    }
  }
  
 ?>
```

If this exact function is put into a JS file, it does not show this "$idx is declared but not used" warning.

Comment: For-loops don't have a separate scope in PHP. All variables outside of the loop are available inside as well. Correct me if I'm wrong, but the "$idx is declared but not used." message is just show by your IDE? It indicates `$idx` is being written to, but never read, so the variable doesn't have any use.

Comment: @vixducis It is in fact being used as the inner variable is being used. Is PHP just different in that way?

Comment: Nowhere in your code the `$idx` is being read. If you would add for example `echo $test` in your code, the warning will disappear.

Comment: @vixducis Then the answer is simple, PHP requires that a variable be used to eliminate that warning. In JS, this is not the case (which is where I come from). The answer to this question:  PHP is different than JS because PHP requires that a variable be read in order for this warning not to take place, whereas in JS, a variable can be either written or read to and will not display this warning.

Comment: Well, the warning is not returned by PHP, but rather by your IDE just indicating that the variable is superfluous and can be removed. If you would run this code by PHP, there wouldn't be a warning. There is nothing wrong with the code itself, your IDE is just making some suggestions to optimize it.

Comment: @vixducis Thank you for the clarification, Ill adjust that in the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple and is due to the differences between JavaScript and PHP in my VSCode IDE and Intellisence.

IDE: VScode

Intellisence: [PHP Intelephence VSCode](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bmewburn.vscode-intelephense-client) extension

In PHP: The variable must be at least `read` to eliminate the warning "$idx is declared but not used."

In JS: The variable must be either at least `written` or `read` to eliminate the warning "$idx is declared but not used."